# How to use two VALUES patterns in the same SPARQL query alternately

Tags: sparql

How can I modify the code below so as the machine to select the suitable VALUES pattern depending on ?description value? Is a modification like this possible???

```
PREFIX e: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/expenses#> 

SELECT ?description ?date ?amount
WHERE
{
  ?meal e:description ?description ;
        e:date ?date ;
        e:amount ?amount .

   VALUES ( ?description ?date) {
             ("lunch" "2011-10-15" ) 
             ("dinner" "2011-10-16" )
      } 

   VALUES ( ?description ?amount) {
         ("breakfast" "2") 
         ("brunch" "5" )
  }       

}
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: You can use SPARQL `UNION`, i.e. `SELECT ... WHERE { {alternative1} UNION {alternative2}}`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do something like:

```
PREFIX e: <http://learningsparql.com/ns/expenses#> 

SELECT ?description ?date ?amount
WHERE
{
  ?meal e:description ?description ;
        e:date ?date ;
        e:amount ?amount .

   VALUES ( ?description ?date         ?amount ) {
          ( "lunch"      "2011-10-15"  UNDEF ) 
          ( "dinner"     "2011-10-16"  UNDEF )
          ( "breakfast"  UNDEF         "2" ) 
          ( "brunch"     UNDEF         "5" )
   }       
}
```

`UNDEF` means that the variable is unbound.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is what I wanted.